# $m\{x\in [0,1]:f'(x)=0\}>0$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f\in C^2\{[0,1],\mathbb{R})$ and $m\{x\in [0,1]:f(x)=0\}>0$. Prove that $$m\{x\in [0,1]:f'(x)=0\}>0,$$ where $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

I don't have any clue to solve this exercise..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can also do this without using knowledge about Lebesgue points as follows:

The idea is that we can remove a countable number of points from a set so that the remaining set is "dense in itself", as follows:
Let

$$
A := \{x \in [0,1] \mid f(x) = 0\}
$$

and

$$
N := \{x \in A \mid \exists \varepsilon_x > 0 \text{ such that } B_{\varepsilon_x} (x) \cap A \text{ is countable}\}.
$$

The **open** covering $(B_{\varepsilon_x}(x))_{x \in N}$ of $N$ has a countable subcover $(B_{\varepsilon_{x_n}}) (x_n)_n$, because $\Bbb{R}$ is second countable.

But this implies that $N \subset \bigcup_n [B_{\varepsilon_{x_n}}(x_n) \cap A]$ is countable as a countable union of countable sets.

Thus, $A \setminus N$ still has positive measure and for each $x \in A \setminus N$, the definition of $N$ shows that $B_\varepsilon (x) \cap (A \setminus \{x\})$ is nonempty (even uncountable), so that there is a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $A \setminus \{x\}$ with $x_n \to x$.

I leave it to you to conclude $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x \in A \setminus N$. Hence, even

$$
m(\{x \mid f'(x) = 0\}) \geq m(A \setminus N) = m(A) > 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! A question to your set $N$: Why is it not possible to just define $N:=\{x\in A | \exists\varepsilon_x>0\text{ such that }B_{e_x}(x)\cap A=\{x\}\}$?

Comment: Ah, so my first answer used too heavy machinery, clearly (+1). I couldn't resist adding another answer, inspired by yours.

Comment: @user181805: Because you want to remove $N$ from $A$. If you do that, it could happen that $B_\varepsilon (x) \cap (A \setminus N) =\{x\}$ for some $x \in A \setminus N$, take for example $A = \{0\} \cup \{1/n \mid n \}$. In this case, $N=A \setminus \{0\}$ with the alternative definition of $N$. With the original definition, this does not happen, because we know that $N$ is countable, but there are uncountably many points of $A$ in each neighbourhood.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite see the problem with this: Each point $x\in A\backslash N$ still has $B_\varepsilon(x)\cap A\supset\{x\}$ and that should be enough, why do I need $B_\varepsilon(x)\cap (A\backslash N)\supset\{x\}$?

Comment: You are right, in your case you only need to know that each point of $A \setminus N$ is a point of accumulation of $A$, not of $A \setminus N$. Side remark: I assume you mean "$\supsetneq$" instead of "$\supset$".

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider [points of density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem) of the set $\{x\in [0,1]:f(x)=0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer, inspired by PhoemueX's answer: Like PhoemuX, define
$$A := \{x \in [0,1] \mid f(x) = 0\}.$$
Now note (as a direct consequence of the definition of the derivative) that if $x\in A$ and $f'(x)\ne0$, then $x$ is an *isolated* point in $A$. No set of real numbers can have more than a countable set of isolated points, and a countable set has measure zero, of course. So $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$ except for a $x$ in a set of measure zero.

This proof only requires the measurability of $f$ and the existence of $f'(x)$ for almost every $x\in[0,1]$ – the stated assumptions in the problem are much stronger than necessary.

Comment: Nice variant of the argument! +1